# Unable to auto rotate screen on Lenovo FLex 5

Tags: gnome, lenovo, 17.04

I got a brand new Lenovo Flex 5 and I installed Ubuntu 17.04 zesty with Gnome 3.24 and Wayland. Unfortunately the screen rotation doesn't work. On the dconf-editor the orientation plugin is Active and the iio-sensor-proxy is already installed. This is a 2-1 laptop and when I flip the screen it doesn't rotate. I had a regular hp probook, no touch screen, no convertible and that machine used to rotate every moment (I had Fedora 26 installed).

What could I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try using Ubuntu 18.04? Screen-rotation works fine on my Flex 5.

Comment: It does work fine on my Lenovo Flex 5 with Ubuntu 18.04.